# XX inch round - radius or diameter?

Tags: meaning

I am looking for some circular labels on eBay ("Warranty void if removed" - I guess you know these things stuck on computers).

[image]

The listing states:

> 100 round bright silver tamper evident hologram labels - Warranty Void If Removed with unique sequential serial numbering.
>
> Dimensions: **.65 inch round**

Does "XX inch round" customarily refer to the radius or the diameter circular things?

Comment: Probably best to ask the seller.

Comment: Probably diameter, but maybe circumference. You have to ask. This is not an English question.

Comment: @Barrie, I guess you know English much better than me!

Comment: It's no clearer to me than it is to you.

Comment: Possibly it is short for an 0.65 inch wide label of the shape "round". Therefore 0.65 is also the diameter of the circular shape it takes.

Comment: @MετάEd, I guess so.

Comment: If it was 0.65" circumference, the diameter would be very small indeed!

Comment: `This is not an English question`. Well, I understand now. `.065 inch round` - this seems to be in Turkish :)

Comment: It would normally be *diameter* rather than *circumference*, for the simple reason that on average people aren't very good at estimating the size of 2d/3d objects from just perimeter/surface area/enclosed volume. But I don't see this is particularly a question about English language, or even specifically about *Anglophones* visuospatial perceptions.

Comment: I rephrased the question; I believe that asking about how a particular phrasing is usually interpreted is on-topic here, even if the answer is "there isn't a usual interpretation."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Size measurements for round objects generally specify the diameter of the object, so normally "0.65 inches round" would be assumed to be a sticker that is 0.65 inches across. This is generally true of buttons, sequins, and other such small sundries.

If it were specifying circumference, it would likely read "0.65 inches around" instead.

Comment: Just as an aside, I find 0.65 inches to be a somewhat odd measurement, in that I would much more expect to see ⅔″ than the remarkably precise ⁶⁵⁄₁₀₀″ instead.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that it is designed to cover a particular size screw hole. A typical rack screw, for instance, has about a 0.21 inch screw head, so you'd have 0.22 inch coverage all around that.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but I'd like to chime in and say that, in any product listing, I wish sellers would use a more precise term (like "diameter") as opposed to ambiguous descriptors such as "round".